# Android set and get data using sharedpreference given error

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, persistence

I want to persistence data using shared preference. but its giving me an error like,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

and

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I am not getting what's problem.
My Code is here,

```
public void setStoreType(List<StoreType> st) {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(StoreType.class, new StoreType());

    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(st, new TypeToken<List<StoreType>>() {
    }.getType());

    if (!element.isJsonObject()) {

    } else {
        pref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("STORE_TYPE", element.getAsJsonObject()
                .toString());
        editor.commit();
    }
}

public List<StoreType> getStoreType() {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(StoreType.class, new StoreType());

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<StoreType>>() {
    }.getType();

    if (gson.fromJson(pref.getString("STORE_TYPE", "{}"), type) == "{}") {
        return new ArrayList<StoreType>();
    }
    return gson.fromJson(pref.getString("STORE_TYPE", "{}"), type);

}
```

I want to set arraylist in it. Please suggest me what is problem in this. Thank you.

Comment: `element.getAsJsonObject()
                .toString()`. Dit you investigate what it contains? What the value is? Then you only have to compare it with `pref.getString("STORE_TYPE", "{}")` to see if they are equal. Now are they? Further if the begin of an array is expected then only for the gson. And then why are you using get as json object? Isnt there a get as json array?

Comment: i also use that. but still same problem every time...

Comment: actually problem is on this line, if (gson.fromJson(pref.getString("STORE_TYPE", "{}"), type) == "{}") {

Comment: `to see if they are equal. Now are they?`. You did not answer.

Comment: so what is solution. say that.